# Binding multiple events jQuery to track Gravity forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to track Gravity forms with Google Tag Manager. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/track-gravity-forms-with-google-tag-manager/) and it works well at the first form on the page. But there are multiple forms, how can I bind also the other **gform_confirmation_loaded** events on a page?

This is the event listener:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(document).bind("gform_confirmation_loaded" , function(event , formID){
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push
            ({
            'event'     : "dn_form_submit",
            'formID'    : formID
            });
        });
  });
```

For example the trigger behind the first form:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [5])
```

And a second:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [38])
```

Comment: What "other" events, this _is_ only this one event _type_. _"and it works well at the first form on the page"_ - and what is the actual problem with the others?

Comment: _"For example the trigger behind the first form:"_ - also unclear what you mean by that; why would you _trigger_ these evens yourself(?) - isn't that supposed to happen _automatically_?

Comment: Every form script created by the Gravity Forms plugin contains this code: jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [7]). 7 is the id of the form. For example, id 7 is a contact form, id 9 a newslettersubscription.

Comment: Then each of those trigger calls should do what the name says, _trigger_ that event handler. So what _is_ the actual problem here? (The mere opposite of "works" alone, is not really a sufficient problem description.)